# How to find the names of all files from the clipboard

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, clipboard

I just created an MFC application to find the file names from the clip board

```
AddClipboardFormatListener(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd->m_hWnd);

LRESULT Cfile_trackerDlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
        {
            AfxBeginThread(FileArrival, NULL);
            break;
        }
    case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
        {
            AfxBeginThread(FileArrival, NULL);
            break;
        }       
    }
    return CDialog::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}

UINT FileArrival(LPVOID param)
{
    TCHAR lpszFileName[MAX_PATH];
    char *szTime;
    time_t thistime;
        OpenClipboard(0);
        HGLOBAL hGlobal = (HGLOBAL)GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP);
        if (hGlobal)
        {
            HDROP hDrop = (HDROP)GlobalLock(hGlobal);
            if (hDrop)
            {   
                time(&thistime);
                szTime = ctime(&thistime);
                DragQueryFile(hDrop, 0, lpszFileName, MAX_PATH);
                WriteLog((char*)lpszFileName,1);
                GlobalUnlock(hGlobal);
            }
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is working fine when we copy 1 file , but when we copy multiple files it only shows the first file. Is there is any method to find out all the file names that copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use this to find the number of files that were dropped:

```
UINT fileCount = DragQueryFile(hDrop, 0xFFFFFFFF, nullptr, 0);
```

With this information, you can allocate an array of strings and store each filename into a string in the array:

```
TCHAR** filenames;
// other code . . .
filenames = malloc(fileCount * sizeof(TCHAR*));
// other code . . .
for (UINT i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i) {
    UINT filenameLength = DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, nullptr, 0);
    filenames[i] = malloc(filenameLength);
    DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, filenames[i], filenameLength);
}
```

I figured this all out from reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776408.aspx).

EDIT: To use the C++ standard library here (prevents having to manually `free` allocated memory), you can use the following code:

```
std::vector<std::basic_string<TCHAR> > filenames(fileCount);
// other code . . .
for (UINT i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i) {
    UINT filenameLength = DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, nullptr, 0);
    filenames[i].reserve(filenameLength);
    DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, &(filenames[i][0]), filenameLength);
    // Uncomment the below line and comment the above line if you can use C++17 features
    // DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, filenames[i].data(), filenameLength);
}
```

Comment: Raw pointers and `malloc` have no place in C++. What's wrong with `vector<wstring>`? Someone already wrote the memory management. There's no reason for you to do it again.

Comment: @IInspectable I have added another solution that uses C++ features. The first solution was continuing the coding style already used in the project.